# How to find characters in a string Assembly x86?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, char

I'm trying to rewrite the C code below in Assembly x86

```
int myFn( char * v, char c, int size ) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i < size; i++ )
    if( v[i] == c )
      return i;
  return -1;
}
```

I've tried to use this code in x86:

```
myFn:
  mov esi, 0
  mov ebx, [esp + 8]
  mov ecx, [esp + 12]

  FOR:
    mov eax, -1
    cmp esi, [esp + 4]
    jge ENDFOR

    cmp [ecx + esi], ebx
    je EQUAL

    inc esi
    jmp FOR
  
  EQUAL:
    mov eax, [esi]
  
  ENDFOR:

  ret
```

I've also created this program to test the function:

```
section .data
  fmt: db "strfind: %d", 10, 0
  str: db "test", 0

section .text
  global main
  extern printf

main:
  mov eax, 's'
  mov ebx, 4

  push str
  push eax
  push ebx
  call myFn
  add esp, 12

  push eax
  push fmt
  call printf
  add esp, 8

  ret

myFn:
  mov esi, 0
  mov ebx, [esp + 8]
  mov ecx, [esp + 12]

  FOR:
    mov eax, -1
    cmp esi, [esp + 4]
    jge ENDFOR

    cmp [ecx + esi], ebx
    je EQUAL

    inc esi
    jmp FOR
  
  EQUAL:
    mov eax, [esi]
  
  ENDFOR:

  ret
```

I'm getting `Segmentation Fault` error or the wrong result when trying to test it. I believe the problem is when comparing the character of the string with the character I want to find

Comment: Multiple problems in there but the immediate cause is likely the `mov eax, [esi]`. You want `mov eax, esi` since `esi` is an index not an address. You ar also comparing 4 bytes instead of 1, clobber callee saved registers and misalign the stack to name a few additional problems.

Comment: There's two comparisons here: `cmp esi, [esp + 4]` which is comparing `i < size` and should be an `int` sized compare.&nbsp; But the other one `cmp [ecx + esi], ebx` for `v[i] == c` should be a `char`/byte-sized compare.

Comment: Yes, so the major problem is with the second comparison, how can I fix it?

Comment: This is memchr; look for simple examples of memchr (although most of what you find if you search for that will be highly optimized).  Or look at compiler output from a C compiler for your C code, although that won't use NASM syntax.  Still, should make it clear when it's using byte operand-size.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)